# How to extend Internet Explorer's share picker on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am stuck now trying to figure out how to enable easy sharing of links from IE to my app. I am trying to figure out how to extend the share picker for Internet Explorer.
  For example, when running IE on WP8, you can bring up the menu at the bottom and click 'share page'. Inside this menu I would like to add my app as an option. Upon selection I would like for it to send the current page's URL to my app.

I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967563%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) but the example only extends the photo app's share picker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to extend the share options in IE mobile in this way.

Comment: Hi Paul, is it possible to add own app into any share menus in built in apps apart from photo app? In particular, Word/Excel?

Comment: That is a huge omission for the platform, which explains  why apps like delicious don't exist, they'd be crippled. Is there info out there on whether this shortcoming will ever be rectified?