# Windows Phone 8 register app for share from IE

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is it possible to register an app on Windows Phone 8 to get the data shared from Internet Explorer?
Just to clarify the scenario: user browses the internet, gets to a page, selects the share menu item and a list of apps appear (Hotmail, SMS etc) and he makes his choice. 
Is it possible to register an app appear in the list of share apps for IE and if yes, how? I know it's possible to register an app to appear in the list of app for pictures (using configuration), but not sure if it's possible for what I want to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extend Internet Explorer's share picker on Windows Phone 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199055/how-to-extend-internet-explorers-share-picker-on-windows-phone-8)

Comment: @AndrasCsehi thank you for your comment and link! I somehow didn't manage to find this thread while searching. Seems like it's not possible to extend the share from IE which is actually a shame :(